# import java class in js

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a html website and I am using JavaScript. 
I have a java Class transformation.java with a method convert(a,b) that I would like use in the javascript in my html document.
How can I import the java class in my java script and use the method convert(a,b)?

Thanks.

Comment: You would definitely need to visit this thread, What is the difference between JavaScript and Java (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Write your self same logic in java script
2. Make a server call to your java function using Javascript using [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/)

Answer (score 5):

Javascript != Java. You cannot import a java class in javascript. The languages are different (despite the names). You need to port the code.

Unless, you want to expose the java code as a servlet and have the javascript invoke it via an AJAX request.

Comment: Actually, exposing the Java code in an Applet might be possible as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. :)
You should check out applets.
[Java Applets](http://java.sun.com/applets/)